# Como agregar una columna a una consulta externa

Tags: sql

yo trabajo con un software el cual exporte una consulta sql que trae varias columnas con datos a la cual le quiero agregar una columna de una tabla diferente.
consulta exportada del software:

```
**SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
SET DATEFORMAT DMY 
SET DATEFIRST 7 
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY -8;
SELECT 
    CPA35.TALONARIO AS [Talonario oc] ,
    CPA35.N_ORDEN_CO AS [Nro. Orden de Compra] ,
    CPA35.COD_PROVEE AS [Cód. proveedor] ,
    CPA01.NOM_PROVEE AS [Razón social] ,
    CASE WHEN CPA35.FEC_GENER = '01/01/1800' THEN NULL ELSE CPA35.FEC_GENER END AS [Fecha de ingreso] ,
    CPA50.NOM_COMPRA AS [Nombre del comprador] ,
    CPA35.COND_COMPR AS [Cód. condición de compra] ,
    CPA36.COD_ARTICU AS [Cód. Artículo] ,
    CPA36.DESCRIPCION_ARTICULO AS [Descripción] ,
    cpa36.COD_DEPOSI AS [Cód. Depósito] ,
    CPA36.CAN_PEDIDA AS [Cantidad pedida] ,
    CPA36.PENDIENTE_FACTURAR AS [Cantidad Pendiente de Facturar] ,
    CASE      WHEN ID_MEDIDA_STOCK_2 IS NULL THEN          (CPA36.PRECIO_PAN * (1 - CPA36.PORC_DCTO / 100) * (CPA36.CAN_PEDIDA / CPA36.CAN_EQUIVA)) *          CASE              WHEN CPA35.MON_CTE <> 1 THEN CPA35.COTIZ              ELSE 1          END      ELSE (CPA36.PRECIO_PAN * (1 - CPA36.PORC_DCTO / 100) * (CPA36.CAN_PEDIDA_2 / CPA36.CAN_EQUIVA)) *           CASE               WHEN CPA35.MON_CTE <> 1 THEN CPA35.COTIZ               ELSE 1           END  END AS [Total pedido sin impuestos] ,
    CASE  WHEN ID_MEDIDA_STOCK_2 IS NULL THEN  ((CPA36.PRECIO_PAN * (1 - CPA36.PORC_DCTO / 100) * (CPA36.PENDIENTE_FACTURAR / CPA36.CAN_EQUIVA )) *  CASE      WHEN CPA35.MON_CTE <> 1 THEN CPA35.COTIZ      ELSE 1  END)  ELSE ((CPA36.PRECIO_PAN * (1 - CPA36.PORC_DCTO / 100) * (CPA36.PENDIENTE_FACTURAR_2)) *   CASE       WHEN CPA35.MON_CTE <> 1 THEN CPA35.COTIZ       ELSE 1   END)  END AS [Pendiente de facturar sin impuestos] ,
    CASE CPA35.ESTADO        WHEN 1                   THEN 'INGRESADA'       WHEN 2                   THEN 'APROBADA'        WHEN 3                   THEN 'EMITIDA'         WHEN 4                   THEN 'DESAUTORIZADA'   WHEN 5                   THEN 'INGRESADA Y ANULADA'     WHEN 6                           THEN 'AUTORIZADA Y REVISADA'   WHEN 7                         THEN 'EMITIDA Y ANULADA'     WHEN 8                         THEN 'EMITIDA Y CERRADA'     WHEN 9                         THEN 'AUTORIZADA PARCIAL'    WHEN 10                        THEN 'CUMPLIDA'              WHEN 11                        THEN 'CERRADA'               ELSE ''                       END AS [Estado] ,
    CPA35.COD_COMPRA AS [Cód. comprador] ,
    CPA36.N_RENGL_OC AS [Renglón OC] 
FROM 
 CPA35                                      
INNER JOIN CPA50 ON CPA35.COD_COMPRA=CPA50.COD_COMPRA     
LEFT JOIN                                                 (SELECT TALONARIO,                                                   N_ORDEN_CO,                                               MIN(FEC_RECEPC) AS FECHA_MINIMA                    FROM CPA37                                                GROUP BY TALONARIO,                                                N_ORDEN_CO) AS TEMP                          ON CPA35.TALONARIO=TEMP.TALONARIO                         AND CPA35.N_ORDEN_CO=TEMP.N_ORDEN_CO                      
LEFT JOIN GVA81                                           ON GVA81.COD_CLASIF=CPA35.COD_CLASIF                      
LEFT JOIN CPA01                                           ON CPA35.COD_PROVEE = CPA01.COD_PROVEE                    
INNER JOIN CPA36                                          ON CPA36.N_ORDEN_CO = CPA35.N_ORDEN_CO                    AND CPA36.TALONARIO = CPA35.TALONARIO                     
INNER JOIN CPA56                                          ON CPA56.TALONARIO=CPA35.TALONARIO                        
LEFT JOIN CPA57 ON CPA01.PROVINCIA = CPA57.COD_PROVIN      
LEFT JOIN CPA108 ON CPA57.COD_PAIS = CPA108.COD_PAIS        
LEFT JOIN(                                                                     SELECT DISTINCT CPA49.COD_CONDIC,  CPA49.DESC_CONDI                 FROM CPA49 ) AS COND ON COND.COD_CONDIC = CPA35.COND_COMPR     
INNER JOIN STA22                                           ON CPA36.COD_DEPOSI=STA22.COD_SUCURS                       
LEFT JOIN CPA43                                            ON CPA43.COD_LISTA=CPA35.COD_LISTA                         
LEFT JOIN                                                                              (                                                                                          SELECT CPA36.N_ORDEN_CO,                                                                      CPA36.TALONARIO                                                                 FROM CPA36                                                                             
LEFT JOIN STA11                                                                        ON STA11.COD_ARTICU=CPA36.COD_ARTICU                                                   WHERE(Sta11.ID_MEDIDA_STOCK=STA11.ID_MEDIDA_CONTROL_STOCK                                AND CPA36.PENDIENTE_FACTURAR > 0                                                        OR Sta11.ID_MEDIDA_STOCK <> STA11.ID_MEDIDA_CONTROL_STOCK                             AND CPA36.PENDIENTE_FACTURAR_2 > 0)                                                   AND (Sta11.ID_MEDIDA_STOCK=STA11.ID_MEDIDA_CONTROL_STOCK                                        AND CPA36.PENDIENTE_FACTURAR <> CPA36.CAN_PEDIDA                                OR Sta11.ID_MEDIDA_STOCK <> STA11.ID_MEDIDA_CONTROL_STOCK                                  AND CPA36.PENDIENTE_FACTURAR_2 <> CPA36.CAN_PEDIDA_2                                 )                                                                                  AND (Sta11.ID_MEDIDA_STOCK=STA11.ID_MEDIDA_CONTROL_STOCK                                    AND CPA36.CAN_PENDIE > CPA36.PENDIENTE_FACTURAR                                     OR Sta11.ID_MEDIDA_STOCK<>STA11.ID_MEDIDA_CONTROL_STOCK                                  AND CPA36.CAN_PENDIE_2 > CPA36.PENDIENTE_FACTURAR_2                                    )                                                                                 GROUP BY CPA36.N_ORDEN_CO,                                                                      CPA36.TALONARIO) AS FACTURADO                                            ON FACTURADO.TALONARIO=CPA35.TALONARIO                                                 AND FACTURADO.N_ORDEN_CO=CPA35.N_ORDEN_CO                                               
LEFT JOIN MEDIDA MEDIDA_STOCK                                                           ON MEDIDA_STOCK.ID_MEDIDA = CPA36.ID_MEDIDA_STOCK                                     
LEFT JOIN MEDIDA MEDIDA_STOCK_2                                             ON MEDIDA_STOCK_2.ID_MEDIDA = CPA36.ID_MEDIDA_STOCK_2 
WHERE 
   CPA35.Estado NOT IN(5, 6,7,11)  AND CPA36.PENDIENTE_FACTURAR>0**
```

A esta consulta le quiero agregar una columna que encontre haciendo un join

```
select NRO_SOLIC  from cpa35 on cpa123.id_cpa35 = cpa35.id_cpa35
```

Nose si lo estoy haciendo bien pero en teoria quiero agregar a esta consulta externa una sola columna que se encuentra en la tabla cpa123

Answer (score 0):

Para ello debes agregar un JOIN con la tabla cpa123 a la consulta actual (`LEFT JOIN cpa123 ON cpa123.id_cpa35 = cpa35.id_cpa35`), y luego la columna en el select principal (`cap123.NRO_SOLIC`).

Hay diferentes tipos de JOINs, en este caso yo use LEFT JOIN que te va a traer todas las filas que traía la consulta aunque no haya una fila que machee en cpa123.

No se si eso es lo que necesitas. Fijate que edité tu query y agregué las dos lineas separadas para que las puedas identificar.

```
SELECT 
     CPA35.TALONARIO AS [Talonario oc] ,
     CPA35.N_ORDEN_CO AS [Nro. Orden de Compra] ,
     CPA35.COD_PROVEE AS [Cód. proveedor] ,
     CPA01.NOM_PROVEE AS [Razón social] ,
     CASE WHEN CPA35.FEC_GENER = '01/01/1800' THEN NULL ELSE CPA35.FEC_GENER END AS [Fecha de ingreso] ,
     CPA50.NOM_COMPRA AS [Nombre del comprador] ,
     CPA35.COND_COMPR AS [Cód. condición de compra] ,
     CPA36.COD_ARTICU AS [Cód. Artículo] ,
     CPA36.DESCRIPCION_ARTICULO AS [Descripción] ,
     cpa36.COD_DEPOSI AS [Cód. Depósito] ,
     CPA36.CAN_PEDIDA AS [Cantidad pedida] ,
     CPA36.PENDIENTE_FACTURAR AS [Cantidad Pendiente de Facturar] ,
     CASE   WHEN ID_MEDIDA_STOCK_2 IS NULL THEN (CPA36.PRECIO_PAN * (1 - CPA36.PORC_DCTO / 100) * (CPA36.CAN_PEDIDA / CPA36.CAN_EQUIVA)) * CASE  WHEN CPA35.MON_CTE <> 1 THEN CPA35.COTIZ  ELSE 1 END   ELSE (CPA36.PRECIO_PAN * (1 - CPA36.PORC_DCTO / 100) * (CPA36.CAN_PEDIDA_2 / CPA36.CAN_EQUIVA)) *  CASE   WHEN CPA35.MON_CTE <> 1 THEN CPA35.COTIZ   ELSE 1  END  END AS [Total pedido sin impuestos] ,
     CASE  WHEN ID_MEDIDA_STOCK_2 IS NULL THEN  ((CPA36.PRECIO_PAN * (1 - CPA36.PORC_DCTO / 100) * (CPA36.PENDIENTE_FACTURAR / CPA36.CAN_EQUIVA )) *  CASE   WHEN CPA35.MON_CTE <> 1 THEN CPA35.COTIZ   ELSE 1  END)  ELSE ((CPA36.PRECIO_PAN * (1 - CPA36.PORC_DCTO / 100) * (CPA36.PENDIENTE_FACTURAR_2)) *   CASE WHEN CPA35.MON_CTE <> 1 THEN CPA35.COTIZ ELSE 1   END)  END AS [Pendiente de facturar sin impuestos] ,
     CASE CPA35.ESTADO  WHEN 1 THEN 'INGRESADA' WHEN 2 THEN 'APROBADA'  WHEN 3 THEN 'EMITIDA'   WHEN 4 THEN 'DESAUTORIZADA'   WHEN 5 THEN 'INGRESADA Y ANULADA'  WHEN 6   THEN 'AUTORIZADA Y REVISADA'   WHEN 7 THEN 'EMITIDA Y ANULADA'  WHEN 8 THEN 'EMITIDA Y CERRADA'  WHEN 9 THEN 'AUTORIZADA PARCIAL' WHEN 10   THEN 'CUMPLIDA'  WHEN 11   THEN 'CERRADA'   ELSE ''  END AS [Estado] ,
     CPA35.COD_COMPRA AS [Cód. comprador] ,
     CPA36.N_RENGL_OC AS [Renglón OC],

     cap123.NRO_SOLIC

FROM  CPA35  

INNER JOIN CPA50 ON CPA35.COD_COMPRA=CPA50.COD_COMPRA  
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TALONARIO,   N_ORDEN_CO,  MIN(FEC_RECEPC) AS FECHA_MINIMA  FROM CPA37   GROUP BY TALONARIO,   N_ORDEN_CO) AS TEMP ON CPA35.TALONARIO=TEMP.TALONARIO AND CPA35.N_ORDEN_CO=TEMP.N_ORDEN_CO 
LEFT JOIN GVA81 ON GVA81.COD_CLASIF=CPA35.COD_CLASIF 
LEFT JOIN CPA01 ON CPA35.COD_PROVEE = CPA01.COD_PROVEE  
INNER JOIN CPA36   ON CPA36.N_ORDEN_CO = CPA35.N_ORDEN_CO  AND CPA36.TALONARIO = CPA35.TALONARIO   
INNER JOIN CPA56   ON CPA56.TALONARIO=CPA35.TALONARIO   
LEFT JOIN CPA57 ON CPA01.PROVINCIA = CPA57.COD_PROVIN   
LEFT JOIN CPA108 ON CPA57.COD_PAIS = CPA108.COD_PAIS  
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT CPA49.COD_CONDIC,  CPA49.DESC_CONDI  FROM CPA49 ) AS COND ON COND.COD_CONDIC = CPA35.COND_COMPR  
INNER JOIN STA22 ON CPA36.COD_DEPOSI=STA22.COD_SUCURS  
LEFT JOIN CPA43  ON CPA43.COD_LISTA=CPA35.COD_LISTA 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT CPA36.N_ORDEN_CO, CPA36.TALONARIO  FROM CPA36  
    LEFT JOIN STA11 ON STA11.COD_ARTICU=CPA36.COD_ARTICU   
    WHERE(Sta11.ID_MEDIDA_STOCK=STA11.ID_MEDIDA_CONTROL_STOCK  AND CPA36.PENDIENTE_FACTURAR > 0  OR Sta11.ID_MEDIDA_STOCK <> STA11.ID_MEDIDA_CONTROL_STOCK  AND CPA36.PENDIENTE_FACTURAR_2 > 0) AND (Sta11.ID_MEDIDA_STOCK=STA11.ID_MEDIDA_CONTROL_STOCK AND CPA36.PENDIENTE_FACTURAR <> CPA36.CAN_PEDIDA  OR Sta11.ID_MEDIDA_STOCK <> STA11.ID_MEDIDA_CONTROL_STOCK AND CPA36.PENDIENTE_FACTURAR_2 <> CPA36.CAN_PEDIDA_2   ) AND (Sta11.ID_MEDIDA_STOCK=STA11.ID_MEDIDA_CONTROL_STOCK   AND CPA36.CAN_PENDIE > CPA36.PENDIENTE_FACTURAR OR Sta11.ID_MEDIDA_STOCK<>STA11.ID_MEDIDA_CONTROL_STOCK AND CPA36.CAN_PENDIE_2 > CPA36.PENDIENTE_FACTURAR_2   ) GROUP BY CPA36.N_ORDEN_CO, CPA36.TALONARIO) AS FACTURADO  ON FACTURADO.TALONARIO=CPA35.TALONARIO AND FACTURADO.N_ORDEN_CO=CPA35.N_ORDEN_CO  
LEFT JOIN MEDIDA MEDIDA_STOCK  ON MEDIDA_STOCK.ID_MEDIDA = CPA36.ID_MEDIDA_STOCK 
LEFT JOIN MEDIDA MEDIDA_STOCK_2   ON MEDIDA_STOCK_2.ID_MEDIDA = CPA36.ID_MEDIDA_STOCK_2 

LEFT JOIN cpa123 ON cpa123.id_cpa35 = cpa35.id_cpa35

WHERE CPA35.Estado NOT IN(5, 6,7,11)  AND CPA36.PENDIENTE_FACTURAR > 0
```